# Get value out of array by name

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to get a value out of an array by name.  The purpose of this is to send these parameters to both SSRS and to a transactional query.

I have an XML type ParameterValue:

```
'report paramerters
Dim parametersTransactional(3) As ParameterValue

parametersTransactional(0) = New ParameterValue()
parametersTransactional(0).Name = "StartDate"
parametersTransactional(0).Value = "2012-01-01T00:00:00"

parametersTransactional(1) = New ParameterValue()
parametersTransactional(1).Name = "EndDate"
parametersTransactional(1).Value = "2012-06-01T00:00:00"

parametersTransactional(2) = New ParameterValue()
parametersTransactional(2).Name = CustomersCustomerLocation"
parametersTransactional(2).Value = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

I thought I could get the index of a name then get the value like this;

```
Dim startDate As String = "StartDate"
Dim idxStartDate As Integer = Array.IndexOf(parameters, startDate)
```

Or like this:

```
Dim start2 As Integer = parameters.FindIndex(startDate)
```

ParameterValue is of type:

```
'''<remarks/>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.17929"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices")>  _
Partial Public Class ParameterValue
Inherits ParameterValueOrFieldReference

Private nameField As String

Private valueField As String

Private labelField As String

'''<remarks/>
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return Me.nameField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.nameField = value
    End Set
End Property

'''<remarks/>
Public Property Value() As String
    Get
        Return Me.valueField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.valueField = value
    End Set
End Property

'''<remarks/>
Public Property Label() As String
    Get
        Return Me.labelField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.labelField = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

So I'm missing some crucial step.

Comment: Sounds like you want a dictionary instead of an array?

Comment: @ crashmstr I could. ParameterValue is a value I can send to SSRS. I also want to extract the values into individual parameters to use in a transactional query. Should I loop through ParameterValue and place the values in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that easily using the `First` or `FirstOrDefault` method.  They are both LINQ extension methods.  For instance:

```
Dim p As ParameterValue = parameters.FirstOrDefault(function(x) x.Name = "StartDate")
```

Comment: Yup, that worked! It looks like this:Dim p As ParameterValue = parameters.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "StartDate")
            Dim startDate As String = p.Value.ToString()

Answer (score 1):

You second attempt was getting close.  something like this will work:

```
Dim startdate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(parametersTransactional(Array.FindIndex(parametersTransactional, Function(x) x.Name = "StartDate")).Value)
```